# how to set some application to run only as root

Tags: permissions, execute-command

I'm running Ubuntu **14.04** and I was wondering is there a way to *set* some applications to *run only* as **root**?

for example the application **X** can normally executed by *any user*, and I want to set it to be executed only as *root*. how could I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, set the owner of the application to root (if it isn't already):

```
sudo chown root:root /path/to/app
```

Then configure rights with chmod, e.g.:

```
sudo chmod 700 /path/to/app
```

This would give root the right to read, write and execute while all other users have no rights. There are other possible combinations. The number 4 is for read, 2 for write and 1 for execute, just add up whatever you want.

If your command is `chmod xyz`, x would be the rights for owner, y for the group and z for others.